# Access dynamic function name in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I have a js file that exports a function `myFunction`. Then, I have another function defined outside the exported module. How can I access it dynamically by its name?

I'm trying in this way but it doesn't work:

```js
exports.myFunction = () => {
    let functionName = 'helperFunction';
    global[functionName]();
}

const helperFunction = () => {
    console.log('helperFunction invoked');
}
```

I'm trying with the global scope `global[functionName]();`, but doesn't work. What is the scope of the helper function?

The reason why helperFunction is outside the export is because I export multiple functions in the same file that call helperFunction.

Comment: did you tried to define "const helperFunction = () => { ... }" before exports ??

Comment: Just tried, getting the same error `TypeError: ["helperFunction"] is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:
Use *eval*.

Hi there,

I tell you one thing about hoisting and then answer your question.

Now that you have defined your *helperFunction* after the export, it might cause a problem because of a JS behaviour called *hoisting*. The declaration of *helperFunction* is recognized in *myFunction*, but not the initialization. That will give you the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'helperFunction' before initialization
```

So, just move the *helperFunction* to the top of the file.

Now, to the actual answer. As you might have realized your *helperFunction* is actually in scope and you *can* call it. To do this, you need to **evaluate** the string: `helperFunction()`. You can use the following snippet:

```js
console.log('hi');
let functionName = 'helperFunction';
eval(`${functionName}()`);
console.log('bye');
```

***Bonus***: what you are actually doing with your code is creating an array with one string element and *call* that array. That, of course, throws the following error:

```
TypeError: [functionName] is not a function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not a big fan of `eval`, but I will use it if I don't have any other choices.
Good point regarding the hoisting issue, but it works when I call the function regularly (with helperFunction()) and leave it as it is currently defined below the exported function, so that shouldn't be the issue in this case.

Comment: Sure, eval is always like playing with fire in your bedroom.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking, you can make it work with global.

```
global.helperFunction = () => {
    console.log('helperFunction invoked');
}

const myFunction = () => {
    let functionName = 'helperFunction';
    global[functionName]();
}
```

Whether or **not** this is a good idea... well, that's an entirely different discussion.
I don't know any details, but using Classes is usually the way to go in these cases.